# upgrade nuxt 2.12 to 2.15.8 error "this dependency was not found"?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm trying to upgrade nuxt from 2.12 to 2.15.8 https://prnt.sc/1xrq08s and I get an error, how can I fix it?

**error message:**

> This dependency was not found:
> /Users/twic/var/www/d-front/.nuxt/client.js in multi ./node_modules/eventsource-polyfill/dist/browserify-eventsource.js (webpack)-hot-middleware/client.js?reload=true&timeout=30000&ansiColors=&overlayStyles=&path=%2F__webpack_hmr%2Fclient&name=client ./.nuxt/client.js

> To install it, you can run: npm install --save /Users/twic/var/www/d-front/.nuxt/client.js

**package.json:**

```
{
  "name": "name pr",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "name prs desck",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "backpack dev",
    "build": "nuxt build && backpack build",
    "start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node .nuxt/dist/main.js",
    "generate": "nuxt generate",
    "analyze": "nuxt build --analyze",
    "pm2": "pm2 start ecosystem.config.js",
    "lint:js": "eslint --ext .js,.vue --ignore-path .gitignore .",
    "lint:css": "stylelint \"./**/*.scss\" \"./**/*.vue\"",
    "lint": "npm run lint:js && npm run lint:css",
    "deploy": "pm2 stop 0 && npm ci && npm run build && pm2 start 0"
  },
  "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-commit": "npm run lint"
    }
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.15.8",
    "@epegzz/sass-vars-loader": "^6.0.0",
    "@koa/cors": "^3.0.0",
    "@nuxtjs/axios": "^5.9.5",
    "@nuxtjs/dotenv": "^1.4.1",
    "@nuxtjs/style-resources": "^1.2.1",
    "cookie-universal-nuxt": "^2.1.3",
    "ctx-polyfill": "^1.1.4",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "flickity": "^2.2.1",
    "gsap": "^3.2.3",
    "husky": "^7.0.4",
    "koa": "^2.11.0",
    "koa-router": "^8.0.7",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "marker-clusterer-plus": "^2.1.4",
    "nuxt": "^2.15.8",
    "object-fit-images": "^3.2.4",
    "object-fit-videos": "^1.0.4",
    "pnpapi": "^0.0.0",
    "to-pascal-case": "^1.0.0",
    "v-mask": "^2.0.2",
    "vue-click-outside": "^1.0.7",
    "vue-js-modal": "^1.3.33",
    "vue-youtube-embed": "^2.2.2",
    "vue2-google-maps": "^0.10.7",
    "vue2-transitions": "^0.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/runtime-corejs3": "^7.15.4",
    "@nuxt/types": "^2.15.8",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.3",
    "backpack-core": "^0.8.4",
    "chalk": "^3.0.0",
    "chokidar": "^3.3.1",
    "core-js": "3.19.0",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.0",
    "css-loader": "^5.2.7",
    "eslint": "^8.1.0",
    "eslint-config-standard": "^14.1.0",
    "eslint-friendly-formatter": "^3.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.20.1",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "^11.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^4.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-standard": "^4.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^8.0.1",
    "ip": "^1.1.5",
    "loader-runner": "^3.1.0",
    "node-sass": "^6.0.1",
    "node-sass-utils": "^1.1.3",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.2",
    "postcss": "^8.3.11",
    "postcss-import": "^14.0.2",
    "postcss-loader": "^4.3.0",
    "postcss-url": "^10.1.3",
    "request": "^2.88.2",
    "sass-loader": "^10.1.1",
    "stylelint": "^13.2.0",
    "stylelint-config-recess-order": "^2.0.3",
    "stylelint-config-standard": "^20.0.0",
    "stylelint-webpack-plugin": "^1.2.3",
    "terser-webpack-plugin": "^2.3.4",
    "vue-style-loader": "^4.1.2",
    "vue-svg-loader": "^0.10.0",
    "webpack": "^4.46.0",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.25.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: We are lacking some info here. Are you using NPM or Yarn? What did you type to upgrade to this version? Did any other package change? Is there some other available updates? What is the real version of Nuxt before the upgrade? Also, be careful with the `^` in the `package.json` when speaking of a package because it does mean that a minor version can be installed. More info here: https://michaelsoolee.com/npm-package-tilde-caret/

Comment: Also, you don't have this error while starting the server but just at some point while using the app? Lastly, look at the error in the screenshot, it's talking about postcss, did you checked this one?

Comment: Adding steps taken to reproduce the issue would help us understand the issue better.

Comment: Hi, I managed to solve this problem, I just rolled up the packages and manually update each package

Comment: Feel free to post it as an answer and accept it!

Comment: @ИльяПащук How did you fix it? I am facing the same issue.

Comment: @ИльяПащук as told above: take your package.json, find the concerned packages and downgrade their version to have something matching what is required by the other packages.